# Function to generate radom alphanumeric cookies

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, random

I wrote this python function to generate random values to use as id for the cookies I have on my project.

These are some examples of what the return is:

```
'kck9874118vq{5470553602125615945684311372005'
'72195739g112py3472118v104h122z5038a100d118v912296336399110nu110n60041909'
```

That is the method:

```
def generateCookieID(userName):

    cookieId = ''
    for a in range(0,9):
        aux = randint(0,9999)
        if aux % 2==0:
            for i in range(1,4):
                letter = randint(97,123)
                if letter%2==1:
                    cookieId += chr(letter)
                else:
                    cookieId += str(letter)+chr(letter)
        cookieId += str(aux)   
    cookieJar['name'] = userName
    cookieJar['id'] = cookieId
    return cookieId
```

It works, but is it appropriate to use this way?
What could I do better?

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Why is `cookieId` only randomized when random `aux` is even?

Comment: It is just really, random. 
I wanted to mix letters and numbers and just decided to do this way.
cookieId is always receiving random values, the difference is that when the program reaches the second for loop it will insert letters as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on python 3.6, you can just use the [secrets module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#generating-tokens): which you should be using, in case the random value should be secret.

From the documentation:

```
>>> token_urlsafe(16)  
'Drmhze6EPcv0fN_81Bj-nA'
```

if you're below python 3.6, see [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/secrets.py), how it's implemented. You  might just copy that.

Comment: That is very useful for me, thank you. I am just starting with python

Comment: This is not a review of the original code, but an alternative solution to a coding problem.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I kind of agree, but I also fully agree with this answer. Maybe a sentence discussing why it is bad to roll your own secure tokens would help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the algorithm you provided makes sense, which I doubt, you might still improve your code by implementing [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), using the `string` module and making use of the *boolness* of integers:

```
def generate_cookie_id(user_name):

    cookie_id = ''
    for a in range(0, 9):
        aux = randint(0, 9999)
        if not aux % 2:
            for i in range(1, 4):
                letter = randint(97, 123)
                if letter % 2:
                    cookie_id += chr(letter)
                else:
                    cookie_id += str(letter) + chr(letter)
        cookie_id += str(aux)   
    cookie_jar['name'] = user_name
    cookie_jar['id'] = cookie_id
    return cookie_id
```

Under the assumption that `cookie_jar` is defined within a higher scope.

However, you should not write hash functions on your own.
If you just need a safe, random string, you can use a `uuid.uuid4()`.

Comment: I thought of doing something that does not really follow any logic. I just wanted to try mixing up random numbers and letters. 
The uuid and secrets are good solutions for what I wanted to do though.
To understand better, why should I not hash on my own?
I am trying to learn python

Comment: I would also eliminate the magic numbers `97` and `123` and make them `ord('a')` and `ord('{')` instead.